# TypeScript - Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'xxxxxxx'

Tags: typescript

What should I do when a compiling error "Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'xxxxx'" happens?

```
let rootElement: Element = document.getRootElement();
```

I have this line in my code which cause a compile error.

Type "Element" declared in typescript's lib.d.ts conflicts with Type "Element" declared in d.ts file I installed via npm.

For now, I changed the name of Type declared in the imported d.ts file to something else, but are there other smart ways to solve this conflict problem?

This is the d.ts file causing a conflict issue.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/14fe4313f4a1cf69add3505a2ab1dbc690dc2116/google-apps-script/google-apps-script.xml-service.d.ts

Comment: there's shouldn't be a conflict as the `Element` in `lib.d.ts` has no namespace, but the one in the file you referenced to is under `GoogleAppsScript.XML_Service` so one should be just `Element` while the other is `GoogleAppsScript.XML_Service.Element`.  Maybe you are importing it somehow and by that resulting in a conflict?